# Запись в файл через system() в СИ

Tags: c

Мне нужно записать в текстовый файл некий текст в языке СИ, я хочу это сделать через команду system("copy con file.txt). Но так же как и в cmd, она запрашивает ввод пользователя. Можно ли как то это сделать автоматически, что бы при вводе команды или блока команд программа сама создавала файл и записывала в него текст?

Comment: а почему не читать через getline или чего то подобного? почему Вы хотите именно через system сделать?

Comment: Просто хотел узнать как это сделать.

Comment: fopen(..) + frwite(..) + fclose() и будет все как нужно

Comment: Да, я знаю это, я специально хочу сделать это через system. Вы случайно не знаете как вывести переменную через system("echo")?

Comment: Это я решил сразу добавив команду в переменную уже с нужной информацией, а затем через system(var), записал данные в файл.

Comment: может тогда проще написать скрипт (bat/bash) и просто его запустить?

Comment: Можно, но мне нужно сделать программу на си.

Comment: ну так программа на си создаст этот файл и через system запустит

Comment: "Некий" - это какой? Откуда он берется?

Comment: Некий то есть любой текст который записан в переменную. Я уже написал программу.

Answer (score 2):

Решение:

```
system("echo text>>file.txt");
```

Эта команда создаёт текстовый документ с именем file, и записывает в него слово text.

Comment: Почему это не является ответом на вопрос? Вопрос был в том что бы найти команду для нужного действия. Я сделал ответ в котором эта команда.

Comment: Вопрос — с. Ответ — batch. Нормально ответ вы оформили и на c — было б ок.

Comment: Хорошего дня ;)

Comment: Вам тоже хорошего дня)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, а если всё-таки прочитать вопрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy А что?